# Difference in bash using jupyter with ipython versus R (irkernel)

Tags: bash, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I've got a jupyter/ipython notebook with the following bash script using %% magic that works to search a directory and apply a command to files matching a "bam" file extension

```
%%bash
cd ../data/raw/Alignment_Files/
echo "starting"
for file in *; do
    echo "testing" $file
    if [[ $file = *bam ]]; then
        echo "Processing" $file
        # do something interesting...
    fi
done
```

I'm trying to port it to another notebook using an R kernel (irkernel) and came up with this

```
system('cd ../data/raw/Alignment_Files/
echo "starting"
for file in *; do
    echo "testing" $file
    if [[ $file = *bam ]]; then
        echo "Processing" $file
        # do something interesting...
    fi
done',
intern=TRUE)
```

However the if/then loop doesn't work and I've tried a lot of variations with no success. The R version gives the "starting" and "testing" debug messages, but the if loop never executes. My guess would be that a character needs to be escaped but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `system` probably uses `sh`, not `bash` in most cases.  So you're using different shells in the two examples--though you're using bash syntax

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from Eric Renouf I found the solution by using shell tools (grep) rather than anything bash specific. Since irkernel uses the system shell, not bash.

```
system('cd ../data/raw/Alignment_Files/
echo "starting"
for file in *; do
    echo "testing" $file
    if echo "$file" | grep "bam$"; then
        echo "Processing" $file
        # do something interesting...
    fi
done',
intern=TRUE)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use `os.walk` to do this in python instead of dropping to a shell for it?